# Data grouping algorithm for filter optimisation

Tags: c#, algorithm, filter, can-bus

I am working on a project using an MCP2515 (CAN transceiver) and one of the features of the chip is that I can filter the IDs by applying rules (masks) to let only certain ranges of data pass through the filter. I can have up to 6 different filters. In the application I am coding, I parse a DBC file to select the signals I want to receive. If I have 6 signals or less, i can make a "pass-through rule" for each of these signals, but if I have more than 6 signals, I need to create rules that englobes all the IDs I need. Ideally, each group would englobe the smallest range of data possible. I would like it to be calculated automaticaly, so I need to create a sort of algorithm that would regroup my IDs.

For example, if I have the following IDs selected:
32, 154, 157, 160, 354, 363, 680, 682, 841, 845, 871, 932, 936, 940

My data groups would be [32], [154, 157, 160], [354, 363], [680, 682], [841, 845, 871], [932, 936, 940].

This is the code I have for now, but it has trouble dealing with the ends of the range (in the above case: 32 and 940).

```
private void getMasks()
    {
        List<List<uint>> fields = new List<List<uint>>();

        uint spectrum = 0;
        uint chunkSize = 0;
        IDs.Sort();
        spectrum = IDs.Last() - IDs.First();

        //Gets the sixth of my whole data range for a first grouping
        chunkSize = (uint)Math.Ceiling(((double)spectrum / 6));

        //Regroups data in the 6 ranges
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            fields.Add(new List<uint>());
            foreach (uint id in IDs)
            {
                if (id >= ((i * chunkSize) + IDs.First()) && id < (((i + 1) * chunkSize) - 1) + IDs.First())
                    fields[i].Add(id);                    
            }                
        }

        //If a range doesn't have data, removes it
        for (int j = 0; j < fields.Count; j++)
            if (fields[j].Count == 0)
            {
                fields.RemoveAt(j);
                j--;
            }

        //Reorganize the data in fields to have the smallest range possible in the subgroups
        for(int k = 0; k < fields.Count - 1; k++)
        {
            //MY PROBLEM IS IN THE NEXT TWO LOOPS

            //If the last data in a group is closer from the first data of the next group than from the second last of its own group, moves it to the next group
            while(fields[k].Count >= 2 && fields[k+1].Count > 0 && ((fields[k][fields[k].Count -1] - fields[k][fields[k].Count - 2]) > (fields[k+1][fields[k+1].Count -1] - fields[k][fields[k].Count - 1])))
            {
                fields[k + 1].Add(fields[k].Last());
                fields[k].RemoveAt(fields[k].Count - 1);
            }

            //If the first data in a group is closer to the last data of the last group than to the second data of its own group, moves it to the last group.
            while (fields[k].Count > 0 && fields[k + 1].Count >= 2 && ((fields[k+1][1] - fields[k+1][0]) > (fields[k].Last() - fields[k+1][0])))
            {
                fields[k].Add(fields[k+1][0]);
                fields[k+1].RemoveAt(0);
            }
        } 
        //Some other code to find the masks to apply            
    }
```

Can someone give me hints or examples on how to regroup in the data in the smallest range possible?

Thank You,

Alfred

Comment: Can you explain the rules for grouping? Are you just doing it by hundreds? I don't see how "smallest range between the first and the last IDs of each group" relates to your desired output.

Comment: No, the data is grouped so each data range is the smallest possible. For example, if i take the data listed in the post, if the 354 was in the [154, 157, 160] group, the range of my rule would have to include data from 154 to 354 (a range of 200). In the way it's sorted in the original post, the range for the [154, 157, 160] would then be 6 and the range for the [354, 363] group would be 9.

Comment: I need to have 6 rules that, when applied, filter as much as possible the frames I receive. I then need to have filters that cover all the data I need to receive while limiting as much as possible to receive other data. Using the example i gave in my first answer, if one of my groups has the values [154, 157, 160, 354], the mask that covers this whole range would allow 200 different values, but I only need 4 of them. If I move 354 in the next group (with 363), the rule applying to [154, 157, 160] and [354, 363] would cover (160 - 154) + (363 - 354) = 15 different values out of which I need 5.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your list with calculated "distance" to the next item:

```
32(122), 154(3), 157(3), 160(194), 354(9), 363(317), 680(2), 682(159), 841(4), 845(26), 871(61), 932(4), 936(4), 940()
```

here the same list sorted by "distance" descending:

```
363(317), 160(194), 682(159), 32(122), 871(61), 845(26), 354(9), 841(4), 932(4), 936(4), 154(3), 157(3), 680(2), 940()
```

what you need - take first 5 items:

```
363(317), 160(194), 682(159), 32(122), 871(61)
```

and "split" your original list after these items:

```
32(122)                  // split 4
154(3), 157(3), 160(194) // split 2
354(9), 363(317)         // split 1
680(2), 682(159)         // split 3
841(4), 845(26), 871(61) // split 5
932(4), 936(4), 940()
```

it will give you 6 groups (you cut 5 biggest spaces)

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me for the major part of the day and i was about to give up and find another way to manage the frames i receive.

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> signals = new List<int>() { 680, 841, 154, 940, 160, 157, 936, 354, 363,  682, 871, 932, 845, 32};

            signals.Sort();

            List<GapData> gapsData = new List<GapData>();

            for(int i = 0; i < signals.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                GapData newGap = new GapData() { Index = i, Span = signals[i + 1] - signals[i] };
                gapsData.Add(newGap);
            }

            gapsData.Sort();

            gapsData = gapsData.Take(5).ToList(); //Keep 5 biggest gaps

            gapsData = gapsData.OrderBy(i => i.Index).ToList(); //sort on index

            List<List<int>> groupedList = new List<List<int>>();

            int index = 0;

            List<int> currentGroup = new List<int>();
            groupedList.Add(currentGroup);

            for(int i = 0; i < signals.Count; i++)
            {
                if (index < 5 && gapsData[index].Index < i)
                {
                    currentGroup = new List<int>();
                    groupedList.Add(currentGroup);
                    index++;
                }
                currentGroup.Add(signals[i]);
            }
        }


        public class GapData:IComparable<GapData>
        {
            public GapData()
            {
            }
            public int Index { get; set; }

            public int CompareTo(GapData other)
            {
                return - Span.CompareTo(other.Span);
            }


            public int Span { get; set; }
        }
    }

}
```